# Can`t make gRPC work with Electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, grpc

I`m making an Electron app that should connect by grpc to remote host and call some functions from there.

But I keep getting the following error:
Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\?\D:\Projects\demo-app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\grpc_node.node

I tried to:

1. establish grpc connection from main and from renderer processes of Electron
2. install dependencies as `npm install --unsafe-perm`

   but nothing works.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BQBi.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The gRPC package is distributed with precompiled binaries for Electron, including on Windows, but you have to specify that you're using Electron when you do the installation. The following should work:

```
npm install grpc --runtime=electron --target=<electron version>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a native module, you'll need to rebuild them against your current electron node version.

There is a package called [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) that will do this for you. Basic instructions:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

Then, whenever you install a new npm package, rerun electron-rebuild:

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

Or if you're on Windows:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. I had already upvoted this a few months ago and this answer fixed things for me again today when I was searching for the same problem.